# Meterpreter on non-jailbroken Iphone

Tags: macos, metasploit, iphone, meterpreter

I found this at github: https://github.com/AnwarMohamed/meterpreter-darwin

Does anybody know if this works on a non-jailbroken Iphone?

I downloaded it on my and double-clicked on the Makefile-icon, inside the OSX directory, but my OS just keeps saying: "Makefile" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer".

How can I run the Makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [iOS Hacker's Handbook](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118204123.html), chapter 4, especially the (under "Downloads") downloadable material from chapter 4. It contains a meterpreter that runs on iOS 4 that could possibly be ported to newer versions -- I verified that it does work on iOS 5.

The targeted iPhone in chapter 4 is not jailbroken or otherwise modified.

Comment: btw you will need a working iOS exploit, which may prove difficult on iOS 6 and higher, but here are two methods to do so -- http://www.offensive-security.com/vulndev/evocam-remote-buffer-overflow-on-osx/ -- http://www.exploit-db.com/osx-rop-exploits-evocam-case-study/

Comment: This guy seems to know what he is doing -- http://0vercl0k.tuxfamily.org/bl0g/